# Azure Application Insights - Render ColumnChart as Unstacked

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am putting together a dashboard for our production services and I am trying to create a unified chart of response performance across multiple services.

Now, I can get the the query to run but it created a STACKED column chart but I cannot seem to get it to UNSTACK unless I manually go to the chart properties and change it, but this is not a persistent change as it will reset when you reload / refresh the page.

Here's my query

```
// Create a combined dataset
let mainTable = union pageViews, customEvents, requests
    | where isempty(operation_SyntheticSource)
    | extend name =replace("\n", "", name)
    | extend name =replace("\r", "", name);
// Generate chart data
mainTable
| where duration > 1000 // Not interested in any responses under 1 second
| parse (duration / 1000) // Take the whole number of seconds
with P1: int
    "."
    notInterested: string
| extend peformanceBucket = iff(P1 > 4, ">4", tostring(P1))
| project name, duration, peformanceBucket
| summarize Count = count() by peformanceBucket, name
| order by peformanceBucket
| render columnchart
```

And here's the output

[image]

But this is what I want (by default)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can get the the query to run but it created a STACKED column chart but I cannot seem to get it to UNSTACK unless I manually go to the chart properties and change it, but this is not a persistent change as it will reset when you reload / refresh the page.

If you want to show the ***Unstacked*** **Chart Type** use the **Kind** property has ***Unstacked***.

#### Workaround follows:

##### The query I have used in my Application Insights

```
exceptions 
| summarize count = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 3h), problemId
| order by timestamp asc, problemId
| render columnchart kind=unstacked
```

#### Result

[image]

#### After Adding in Dashboard

[image]

Comment: How do you color the columns?

Comment: @OliverNilsen it is done automatically when the results are group by, in the example group by `problemId`